# 数値チェックでNumberUtilsを使用したいが取り消し線が表示される。

Tags: spring-boot, java8

数値チェックで「org.apache.commons.lang.NumberUtils」を使いたいためにpom.xmlに下記を追記し、JavaファイルにNumberUtils.isNumberを記載するとEclipse上で取り消し線が引かれて「使用すべきではありません。 」と表示されます。なぜでしょうか。
Frameworkは「spring boot」を使用しています。Javaのバージョンは1.8です。

    commons-lang
    commons-lang
    2.6

```
String a = "aaa";
boolean hantei = NumberUtils.isNumber(a);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.apache.commons.lang.NumberUtils`は非推奨(deprecated)になっていて、`org.apache.commons.lang.math.NumberUtils`や`org.apache.commons.lang3.math.NumberUtils`を利用することが推奨されているからです。

[Javadoc](http://www.jajakarta.org/commons/lang-2.0/ja/withoutPrimary/org/apache/commons/lang/NumberUtils.html)にある通り、

> 推奨されていません。 org.apache.commons.lang.math に移動しました。 このクラスは Commons Lang 3.0 では削除されます。

です。`org.apache.commons.lang3.math.NumberUtils`を利用する場合のMavenの`dependency`は以下の通りです。

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Javadocに以下のように`@deprecated`と書かれたメソッドは非推奨のメソッドで、Eclipseで利用しようとすると、警告が表示されます。`org.apache.commons.lang.NumberUtils`も非推奨のメソッドの一つです。

```
/**
 *  コメントの説明文
 *  @deprecated 別のメソッドに置き換えられました
 */
```